# Capture Coordinates in Google Map on User Click

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using this code to capture the co-ordinates when user clicks on the map by using below event listener:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

However this function doesn't get called when user click on already marked location in Map.
Meaning this function is not called for points where mouse pointer changes to hand icon on Google Map.

Need help on capturing these kind of locations.

Answer (score 53):

You should add the click listener on marker will give you the position of marker.

```
//Add listener
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    console.log( latitude + ', ' + longitude );
}); //end addListener
```

Edit:
You need something like this

```
//Add listener
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    console.log( latitude + ', ' + longitude );

    radius = new google.maps.Circle({map: map,
        radius: 100,
        center: event.latLng,
        fillColor: '#777',
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        strokeColor: '#AA0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        draggable: true,    // Dragable
        editable: true      // Resizable
    });

    // Center of map
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));

}); //end addListener
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken `alert(this.position);` will alert `[object]`

Comment: Yes so I have added two seperate variables will help you to get individual lat, lng.

Comment: then i guess you should remove the `alert` since it wont be useful

Comment: This works fine for new markers I have added, but I need for pre-existing location on map -- the ones with a circle and dot in center

Comment: Means you would like to add Circle on Map when user click on Map ? at current position of click.

Comment: Oh thanks @MichaelGeary for suggestion i don't know about that.

Comment: I want to capture latitude & longitude of point of interest (circle with a dot)

Comment: any example have you seen please give link so will check to understand.

Comment: right now i have bind the marker click event when you click on marker will get the current lat, lng of marker and draw circle or 100 meter with marker as center point.

Comment: Hey @MichaelGeary can you see here `this.position` in which `this` refer to `marker` will `marker.position.lat()` should be use or `event.latLng.lat()` is event object give me the Marker position or Mouse Position?

Comment: If I want to get the mouser position ( Cursor ) on map then I should use `this.position` instead of `event` Object?

Comment: Or I will be get the position information inside the `event` object itself?

Answer (score 14):

Another solution is to place a polygon over the map, same size as the map rectangle, and collect this rectangles clicks.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
      var lat1 = 37.41463623043073;
      var lat2 = 37.46915383933881;
      var lng1 = -122.1848153442383;
      var lng2 = -122.09898465576174;  

      var rectangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
         paths : [
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1),
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng1),
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2),
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng2)
         ],
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        fillOpacity : 0,
        map : map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function(args) {  
         console.log('latlng', args.latLng);
    });
  });
}
```

Now you get LatLng's for places of interest (and their likes) also.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qmhku4dh/**

Comment: but what if the user clicked outside of the rectangle?

Answer (score 4):

You're talking about the Point of Interest icons that Google puts on the map.

Would it work for you to remove these icons entirely? You can do that with a Styled Map. To see what this would look like, open the [Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) and navigate the map to the area you're interested in.

Click **Point of interest** under **Feature type**, and then click **Labels** under **Element type**. Finally, click **Visibility** under **Stylers** and click the **Off** radio button under that.

This should remove all of the point of interest icons without affecting the rest of the map styling. With those gone, clicks there will respond to your normal map click event listener.

The **Map Style** box on the right should show:

**Feature type:** poi
**Element type:** labels
**Visibility:** off

If the result looks like what you want, then click **Show JSON** at the bottom of the **Map Style** box. The resulting JSON should like this this:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can use that JSON (really a JavaScript object literal) using code similar to the examples in the [Styled Maps developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). Also see the [MapTypeStyle reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle) for a complete list of map styles.

Comment: I used this code to put the poi labels off. Not the best solution I wanted, but good enough for now.


 var styles = [
       {
         featureType: "poi",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" } ]
         }
        ];
   
   var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,  {name: "Styled Map"});
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),   mapOptions);

     //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
     map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
     map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

Comment: +1 Yes, but you may need to have those icons on the map, for various reasons -  like the customer says : Where is the icons? and think it is an error or a disabled map :)

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates the use of click event listeners on POIs (points of interest). It listens for the click event on a POI icon and then uses the placeId from the event data with a directionsService.route request to calculate and display a route to the clicked place. It also uses the placeId to get more details of the place.

[Read the google documentation.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-poi)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>POI Click Events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }
      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <img id="place-icon" src="" height="16" width="16">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var origin = {lat: -33.871, lng: 151.197};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 18,
          center: origin
        });
        var clickHandler = new ClickEventHandler(map, origin);
      }

      /**
       * @constructor
       */
      var ClickEventHandler = function(map, origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.map = map;
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        this.infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        this.infowindow.setContent(this.infowindowContent);

        // Listen for clicks on the map.
        this.map.addListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
      };

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.handleClick = function(event) {
        console.log('You clicked on: ' + event.latLng);
        // If the event has a placeId, use it.
        if (event.placeId) {
          console.log('You clicked on place:' + event.placeId);

          // Calling e.stop() on the event prevents the default info window from
          // showing.
          // If you call stop here when there is no placeId you will prevent some
          // other map click event handlers from receiving the event.
          event.stop();
          this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(event.placeId);
          this.getPlaceInformation(event.placeId);
        }
      };

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.calculateAndDisplayRoute = function(placeId) {
        var me = this;
        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: this.origin,
          destination: {placeId: placeId},
          travelMode: 'WALKING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      };

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.getPlaceInformation = function(placeId) {
        var me = this;
        this.placesService.getDetails({placeId: placeId}, function(place, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.infowindow.close();
            me.infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
                place.formatted_address;
            me.infowindow.open(me.map);
          }
        });
      };
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm load-google-maps-api with webpack this worked for me:

```
  const loadGoogleMapApi = require("load-google-maps-api");
  loadGoogleMapApi({ key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY }).then(map => {
    let mapCreated = new map.Map(mapElem, {
      center: { lat: lat, lng: long },
      zoom: 7
    });
    mapCreated.addListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(e.latLng.lat()); // this gives you access to the latitude value of the click
       console.log(e.latLng.lng()); // gives you access to the latitude value of the click
      var marker = new map.Marker({
        position: e.latLng,
        map: mapCreated
      });
      mapCreated.panTo(e.latLng); // finally this adds red marker to the map on click.

    });
  });
```

Next if you are integrating openweatherMap in your app you can use the value of e.latLng.lat() and e.latLng.lng() which I console logged above in your api request. This way:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${e.latLng.lat()}&lon=${e.latLng.lng()}&APPID=${YOUR_API_KEY}`

I hope this helps someone as it helped me.
Cheers!