# Google Maps: click on the map, and have the lat/long text appear on another page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, browser

I'm making an admin page to enter locations (lat/long) along with descriptive information. Right now, I am finding the spot on the map, clicking a point off to the side of it, and copying the lat/long which I then paste into a text box. I'd like to just find the spot, click it, and have the value auto-filled into the box.

Comment: What does your code look like?  What is the id of the text box?

Comment: It's very basic code, so let's say "box1".

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087352/capture-coordinates-in-google-map-on-user-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(a_map, 'click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.latLng);
});
```

[Google Maps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

[Working example with markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments)

EDIT:

Thanks to PHPglue:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(a_map, 'click', function(event) {
  var evt = event.latLng;
  console.log('latitude:'+evt.lat()+'; longitude:'+evt.lng()+';');
});
```

Comment: I think this will help, as well: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments . Note that `event.latLng` is the `LatLng` Object, so `console.log()` may not work depending on your Browser. Use something like: `var evt = event.latLng; console.log('latitude:'+evt.lat()+'; longitude:'+evt.lng()+';');` in Browsers that don't console complete Objects.

Comment: Was just an example but good to know!, thanks!

Comment: That works great... for future visitors, hit ctrl-shift-j to see the output of this in Chrome. Thank you guys!