# How do you get the geo location of a point on Google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

What i want to do is to use the google api to get the geo location of a point where the user touches on the map.

all I have is just the basic html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA86_aRT8-Gh0fCGcAYCq24UtqLvKAFYAY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: 52.9507709, lng: -1.1746545},
          zoom: 20,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

regards

Comment: Could you make quick fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any solutions or looked up an answered question elsewhere? There is an example here: [Capture Coordinates in Google Map on User Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087352/capture-coordinates-in-google-map-on-user-click)

Also, from Google's documentation:

> UI events within the Google Maps API V3 typically pass an event
>   argument, which can be accessed by the event listener, noting the UI
>   state when the event occurred. For example, **a UI 'click' event
>   typically passes a MouseEvent containing a latLng property denoting
>   the clicked location on the map.** Note that this behavior is unique to
>   UI events; MVC state changes do not pass arguments in their events.
>
> **You can access the event's arguments within an event listener the same
>   way you would access an object's properties.** The following example
>   adds an event listener for the map, and creates a marker when the user
>   clicks on the map at the clicked location.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Use the sample code in your project to set up a jsFiddle or something for people to see.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Google Developers JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events):

Add an event listener that listens for the map `click` event -- that event is then passed a `function` with an argument that contains the information pertaining to the `location` on the map that was clicked. In this example a marker is being placed at the location of every user click on the map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

Comment: If you wanted latitude or longitude, you could also use `event.latLng.lat();` or `event.latLng.lng();`.