# How implement touch map listener on HERE map

Tags: android, here-api

i would like implement something like OnMapClickListener of google maps, this give to me a LatLng object (location) when the map is touched. I see [map gestures guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/map-gestures.html) and the OnTapEvent give to me a point (x,y) not a location (lat, lng).

thank for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture Coordinates in Google Map on User Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087352/capture-coordinates-in-google-map-on-user-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to do something like this:

```
mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MapGesture.OnGestureListener.OnGestureListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTapEvent(PointF p) {
        GeoCoordinate position = map.pixelToGeo(p);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongPressEvent(PointF p) {
        GeoCoordinate position = map.pixelToGeo(p);
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can add a listener to the Fragment itself and make use of the various events which include things like tap, long tap, and double tap. Those events will give you a point which can be converted to latitude and longitude coordinates via the `pixelToGeo` function.

Does that answer your question?

Best,